# PHP session timeout htaccess file

Tags: php, session, timeout

Hi i'm new to programming but am currently working on a session timeout problem.  Basically my session keeps timing out even though i've changed the session.gc_maxlifetime. 
I think another script using the same directory to store session data which doesn't have the maxlifetime set, is running and thus it'll use the shorter value instead. TO combat this i've altered the htaccess file but it is still terminating after an 1hr 30mins, i need it to last for longer.  My htaccess file is below.  I've looked at and tried many of the relevant posts on this board but nothing has worked so far.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
SetEnv PHPRC /home/rocket/public_html/php.ini

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value session.save_path "new/username/php_sessions"
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime "86400"
php_value session.cookie_lifetime "86400"

</IfModule>


# END WordPress
```

Comment: What does `var_dump(ini_get('session.save_path'));`, `var_dump(ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime'));` and `var_dump(ini_get('session.cookie_lifetime'));` show inside your PHP script?

Comment: As a side note I suspect that your last rewrite rule should probably read `RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L]`

Comment: hey, thnks for the reply. Erm would those first 3 be in the php.ini?
 I'm not very good at this lol, but i'm quite new to programming.  The last bit of code where you suggested changing the RewriteRule wasn't written by me and seems to work.  WOuld that code effect the timeout code?

Answer (score 3):

PHP doesn't do with session cookies what you might think it does...

`php_value session.gc_maxlifetime "86400"`

This merely sets the time after which garbage collection *may* occur - since there's only a very small chance that the session data **will** be garbage collected after this time this is unlikely to be the culprit.

`php_value session.cookie_lifetime "86400"`

This sets the time at which the session cookie expires... **but** it doesn't update at `session_start()` therefore, if you start the session on one page, that sets the clock ticking. Moving from page to page won't reset the "clock" so a session with a `cookie_lifetime` of 600 will expire 10 minutes after it was started **not after 10 minutes of inactivity** - you may be seeing this behaviour.

Your best bet is to set `php_value session.cookie_lifetime "0"` this means that the session cookie will expire **only** when the user closes their browser.

If you want to handle an arbitrary expiry that triggers after a period of inactivity it's best to do that in the PHP code by setting a variable within the session, something like `$_SESSION['expires']` and checking/updating/handling that at the start of every page.

Comment: set php_value session.cookie_lifetime "0" is set to 0.  THis might sound very newbie but where and how do you do e $_SESSION['expires']? honestly this isn't my strong suite.  I really feel bad asking :(

Comment: not after 10 minutes of inactivity? What kind of crap the designer think?

Comment: J-16 SDiz - not a very helpful post :(  I'm really struggling here i'v been at this two days now.

Comment: `$_SESSION` is a PHP superglobal (it's an associative array) that references the data in the session, so to set an expiry time you might do something like `if(empty($_SESSION['expires'])) $_SESSION['expires'] = strtotime('+ 10 minutes');` and then do a check at the beginning of the code to see if the session has expired... see "Session basic usage" on PHP.net http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Comment: thank you, i'll check that out.  If i decided to go down that route would i alter and place that kind of code in the php.ini file? or elsewhere?

Comment: I'd guess **not** php.ini - that's the ini file for the PHP interpreter and not for the scripts ... your "program" will be a collection of PHP scripts with names like "index.php" or whatever - I'd suggest spending a bit of time on php.net and getting to grips with the basics of PHP before trying to build a full-blown session managed application... the language has "quirks" :)