# Modify life time of $_SESSION variable in PHP with a .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

i need help to modify life time of my `$_SESSION` variable with a `.htaccess` file.

Actually the `$_SESSION` life time is about `20 min` and it's too fast so i need to change.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704370/php-session-timeout-htaccess-file

Comment: this has already been answered [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206061/session-timeout-in-php-code-and-in-htaccess